# Android : Not able to change the text color of a button programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to change the text color of a button(api: Button) dynamically, but instead of changing to the color, it changes to a gray color and does not change dynamically ?  This is what i am doing, looks pretty straight forward, can someone tell me what is wrong ?

button.setTextColor(R.color.selected_text);

#215F8B
    #FFFFFF

Comment: when you want to change the button text color ?

Comment: can you post selected_txt xml?

Comment: dynamically on click of it... anyway, i have used the parse function.. worked.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hiii arun you can do the following to change the text color of you android button on click event try it

```
btn_no5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
```

If it works please vote

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. More preferred way.

```
btn1.setTextColor(R.color.Aqua);
```

colors.xml (put in the values folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <color name="Aqua">#00FFFF</color>
    </resources>
```

Or you can do this

```
btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use getResources()

```
button.setTextColor(getResources().getString(R.Color.selected_text))
```

And try this.

Comment: yea i guess this was the issue.. :)